# Cannot be resolved to a variable println

Tags: java

I get this error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: studentName cannot be resolved to a variable`

I don't know what's wrong or how to fix it. The error is at the bottom of the code, the second println `System.out.println(studentName);`. Any help would be wonderful.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class allDone {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String studentNames = "";
        String studentScores = "";
        
        while (true){
            //Prompt user to enter Student Name.
            System.out.println("Please Enter StudentName or If Finished Enter alldone:");
            String studentName = in.nextLine();

            if (studentName.equals("alldone")){
                break;
            }
            
            studentNames = studentNames + studentName +";";                          

            System.out.println("Please enter student's score:");

            String studentScore = in.nextLine();

            studentScores = studentScores + studentScore + ";";
        }
        
        String studentNamesArry[] = studentNames.split(";");
        int studentScoresArry[] = getStudentArry(studentScores.split(";"));
        displayHighestScore(studentNamesArry,studentScoresArry);
    }
    
    public static int[] getStudentArry(String[] stringArray){
        int[] studentScoresArry = new int [stringArray.length];
        int i = 0;
        for (String str: stringArray){
            studentScoresArry[i] = Integer.parseInt(str.trim());
            i++;
        }
            
        return studentScoresArry;
    }
        
    public static void displayHighestScore(String studentNamesArry[],int studentScoresArry[]){
        int studentScore = studentScoresArry[0];
                
        for (int i = 1; i < studentScoresArry.length; i++){
            if (studentScoresArry[i] > studentScore){
                studentScore = studentScoresArry[i];
                String studentName = studentNamesArry[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("nHighestScore:");
        System.out.println(studentName);
        System.out.println(studentScore);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this fix your problem?

```java
    public static void displayHighestScore(String studentNamesArry[],int studentScoresArry[]){
        if(studentNamesArry.length > 0 && studentScoresArry.length > 0){
            int studentScore = studentScoresArry[0];
            String studentName = studentNamesArry[0];
                
            for (int i = 1; i < studentScoresArry.length; i++){
                if (studentScoresArry[i] > studentScore){
                    studentScore = studentScoresArry[i];
                    studentName = studentNamesArry[i];
                }
            }
            System.out.println("nHighestScore:");
            System.out.println(studentName);
            System.out.println(studentScore);
        }
    }
```

Note: I added an if statement to check that the arrays were not empty.

Comment: Yes that did fix it, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you just need to initialize studentName earlier because it might not be initialized because of the if statement

```
public static void displayHighestScore(String studentNamesArry[],int studentScoresArry[])
                        {
                    int studentScore = studentScoresArry[0];
                    String studentName="";
                    for (int i = 1; i < studentScoresArry.length; i++)
                            {
                        if (studentScoresArry[i] > studentScore)
                                {
                            studentScore = studentScoresArry[i];
                             studentName = studentNamesArry[i];
                                }
                            }
                    System.out.println("nHighestScore:");
                    System.out.println(studentName);
                    System.out.println(studentScore);
        }
```